# Backend And frontend for an application - Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to ask a question that how to configure a CI system which consists both the admin as well as the frontend section into a single CI installation.

Thanks in advance

J

Comment: one way of doing it is to have a seperate admin folder within the controllers, models and the view folders....the url will then point to http://example.com/controller/admin/login, i've done this in the past and works very well for me..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Phil Sturgeon posted 3 methods for achieving this exact thing with recommendations on where each method may be used. http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2009/07/Create-an-Admin-panel-with-CodeIgniter

Comment: I was going through the same post but can you tell me which one is most optimized?

Comment: Personally I would do one of the following - if your site is small use method 2, if your site is large use method 3.

Comment: +1 I'd always go with #2. doing it by way of #1 is messy. a lot of duplicate code.

Comment: Yea 1 sucks, 2 or 3 based on size.

Comment: From the horse's mouth (not calling you a horse Phil ;) )

Comment: I just looked at that post and 2 is the optimum way unless you are running multiple applications/sites of the same CI install the others are not very good choices

Answer (score 0):

I generally use a standard CI setup; just with a separate controller(s) for the Admin area which controls authentication/admin interface/etcetera.

Then just split down your views into separate folders front/ and admin/

Under those you might have more sub folders

```
admin/settings/user.php
admin/settings/template.php
admin/content/newpage.php
```

and so on

The relative path must be used when loading views contained within subdirectories.

```
$this->load->view('admin/settings/user', $data);
```